# CircuitBreaker 'redis' is OPEN and does not permit further calls ERROR

Tags: python, algorithmic-trading, yfinance

I am currently running an algo that uses yfinance to get historical stock data. It works on most stocks, but on some, it prints this error message:

- LOW: CircuitBreaker 'redis' is OPEN and does not permit further calls
- AXP: Error occurred while retrieving timeseries from Redis, keys: [RedisKey [key=AXP, cluster=finance]]

Could someone please explain what this error means and how I can fix it.

Comment: Came here looking for same. I believe there is inconsistent data being returned as I have seen JSON formatting errors pop up as well. Same data returns with oddball characters that cant be parsed. Thats my best answer still digging in on it as well.

Comment: The purpose of a circuit breaker is to stop using a failed subsystem. Software will ideally be designed to be able to fall back and offer reduced functionality when this happens, rather than not being able to do anything at all. So in this case, redis has failed enough times that it's been determined to be unavailable, so codepaths that use it are no longer available until it's detected to be back up. (The design principles come from the Hystrix library from Netflix, which they use to ensure that their services stay up as a whole even when individual components fail).

Comment: had same issue after requesting many times the same data